# JSON data to JavaScript array

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, api

I'm having problems handling JSON-data as an array in JavaScript.
my JSON array looks like this :

```
    MyArray([['one','two','three'],['four','five','six']]);
```

In JS I am trying to receive it using this method :

```
   $.getJSON('http://test.com/array.json', function(data) {
        alert(data);
   }
```

but i get no data. If i'm using

```
$get('http://test.com/array.json', function(data)
```

instead of $getJSON then i receive my data as a string.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Maybe the respnse isn't **valid** JSON? Otherwise try using $.getJSON and var parsedJSON = JSON.parse(data);

Comment: validate your JSON at [http://jsonlint.com/](http://jsonlint.com/)

Answer (score 2):

Your data is not JSON, but [**JSONP**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP), where `MyArray` is the JSONP callback function.

In theory the web service you're talking to should support a `callback=` parameter which would be what sets the `MyArray` name.

If you just add `&callback=?` then jQuery should automatically generate a randomly named callback function which will then call your `success` function with the required data.

Answer (score 1):

This is no JSON :

```
 MyArray([['one','two','three'],['four','five','six']]);
```

A JSON string isn't simply some javascript you want to evaluate but must start by `[` or `{`.

Look at the norm : http://www.json.org/

As you seem to have a constructor at first, this is probably not even JSONP.

I'd recommend you to make a standard JSON array :

```
"[['one','two','three'],['four','five','six']]"
```

And then use a constructor client side if you need a `MyArray` instance.

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON isn't valid. The format it's in can still be used. Use the `get` method and then try the following:

```
$.get('http://test.com/array.json', function(data) {
  data = data.replace("MyArray(", '"');
  data = data.replace(");", '"');
  var myData = JSON.parse(data); // Converted JSON to object.
}
```